# Ada Generic Linked List and Generic Package Access

Tags: nodes, ada, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to build a generic linked list in Ada off of a generic Node class. However, I'm unable to access types and formal parameters of my Node inside of my Linked List, despite using a `with` clause and prefixing accordingly.

genericnode.ads:

```
generic
   type item_type is private;

package GenericNode is
   type Node is limited private;
   type NodePtr is access Node;
   
   procedure GetData(n : in Node; e : out item_type);
   procedure GetNext(n : in Node; x : out NodePtr);
   
   procedure SetData(n : in out Node; e : in item_type);
   procedure SetNext(n : in out Node; x : in NodePtr);
   
private
   type Node is
      record
         data : item_type;
         next : NodePtr;
      end record;

end GenericNode;
```

genericsll.ads:

```
with GenericNode;

generic
   size : Positive;
   type node_type is private;
package GenericSLL is
   
   type SLL is limited private;
   
   procedure Append(s : in out SLL; d : in GenericNode.item_type);
   
   procedure PrintTraversal(s : in SLL);
   
private
   type SLL is
      record
         head : NodePtr := null;
         length : Positive := 0;
      end record;

end GenericSLL;
```

Upon compilation, I'm told `Invalid prefix in selected component "GenericNode"` and `"NodePtr" is not visible` regarding genericsll.ads. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, consider a [multiway tree](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-8-4.html).

Comment: Why not use `Ada.Containers.Doubly_Linked_Lists`?

Comment: Homework maybe :) It is a good exercise to learn Ada anyway

Comment: Not homework, just trying to apply my Python ADT knowledge to Ada before next semester (one of my classes uses it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With generic packages in Ada, you need to first instantiate them. GenericNode is not a package; it is a recipe for packages, given a type item_type. Both errors are indicative of this problem; the compiler correctly states there is no such package and no such type NodePtr. ('invalid prefix in selected component GenericNode' just means I have no idea what you mean by 'GenericNode')

Where in C++, you might expect indeed to make your singly linked list parameterized on the node type, and then tell the compiler 'just grab the X and Y members of this node type, even though I haven't told you what the node type actually *is* yet', the Ada compiler refuses this because it leads to error-prone code, where you cannot tell what the type should satisfy (contracts in C++20 are meant to patch over this problem).

Ada does not allow this; every package must be instantiated before use, so that the parameters to each type are known. Unfortunately, this also means it is not possible to do arbitrary compile-time computation in Ada as in C++.

If you parameterize GenericSLL on item_type and instead of on node_type, it can instantiate the specific GenericNode package it needs using that item_type. Only GenericSLL needs to be modified:

```
with GenericNode;

generic
   size : Positive;
   type item_type is private;
package GenericSLL is

   package LinkedList_Node is new GenericNode(item_type);
   use LinkedList_Node;

   type SLL is limited private;
   
   procedure Append(s : in out SLL; d : in item_type);
   
   procedure PrintTraversal(s : in SLL);
   
private
   type SLL is
      record
         head : NodePtr := null;
         length : Natural := 0; -- Positive starts at 1
      end record;

end GenericSLL;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I hadn't considered instantiating the generic node inside of my SLL because of prior problems with generic package instantiation inside of other packages.

Comment: I also had to remove the 'is private' clause of my Node type in the GenericNode to allow me to instantiate Nodes such as I do in GenericSLL.Append.

Comment: I use the table on [this wiki page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics) when specifying the contract of a generic package.

Comment: Odd that you needed to remove that 'is private' clause - the table says that `type X is private` would allow 'Any nonlimited definite type: the generic knows that it is possible to assign to variables of this type and to declare objects without initial value.' So instantiation and assignment should be fine. However, probably the problem is that you didn't also give a separate `with function Make_Node return Node_Type` to create nodes with initial value.